# Jenkins jobs configuration checking before run it

Tags: jenkins, jobs, sanitization, master-slave

I would like to check the job configuration before run it on a slave.

Actually, I want to check if the job label matches with the pattern based on the job name.

For example: I want that the job called "test-somename" runs only if it has the label "test-"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing, I am not sure if this is possible or not.

Comment: You can write a custom shell/batch script which try to match the labels of the node (${NODE_LABELS}) with the job name (${JOB_NAME}). If nothing match, the script exits with a error code <> 0. I don't have a better solution...

Comment: Thanks @BrunoLavit
But, I want to check this outside the job in an automatic manner. Lets say that we don't trust job writters

Comment: Understood :) So you can create an "admin" job which monitors your user's jobs.

Comment: As far as I know, the monitoring is after the job is finished.
Could we do something like that but before the job runs? Maybe, when the job is saved?